# Passing specific parameter from previous page to the next page

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need help in passing the specific parameter from the home page to the event details page.
i.e : on the event details title would be the event selected from the home page. I am using ionic version 3

I have tried to pass the parameter using `this.navctrl.push {eventdetailspage , ‘{{event.eventname}}’)` but its not working. PLEASE HELP. Thank you

[image: Homepage]

[image: eventdetailspage]

Answer (score 1):

try like below code :

```
this.navctrl.push('eventdetailspage',{event :event.eventname })
```

Comment: if it will resolve your issue you can mark as solution

Comment: please let me tell what you have pass and which page